# Extending JSON object definition, not a schema

Tags: json

I am attempting to write a system which configures itself based on a set of JSON configuration files.  I have some configuration options which are specific to certain processes but some which are common to all.  Is there a way for me to include a common JSON configuration file into more specific ones.  ex:

Common.json

```
# Common example
{
    "log-level" : "debug",
    "version" : "1.21"
}
```

Specific.json

```
# Specific example
# include <common.json> ????
{
    "config" : {
        "process"  : "distro-center"
        "id"       : "12-3"
        "log-path" : "/var/log/blah"
    }
}
```

So the resulting JSON would effectively be

```
{
    "log-level" : "debug",
    "version" : "1.21"

    "config" : {
        "process"  : "distro-center"
        "id"       : "12-3"
        "log-path" : "/var/log/blah"
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Ruby, unfortunately.